# Is Delta Lake 2.0 compatible with previous versions (eg. 1.2)?

Tags: delta-lake

I used delta lake 1.2 to write some tables, I assume now I can still use 2.0 to do the read and write on those tables. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr Yup! Those tables will still be compatible.

---

Different versions of Delta Lake will add new features (like `OPTIMIZE ZORDER` or using data skipping to speed up queries) and performance improvements. But they do not "break" existing tables. Only protocol upgrades do that.

These Delta Lake versions are all independent of the table protocol version. The table protocol version defines what version of the Delta protocol readers/writers must use. This protocol version is necessary when certain new features, like column mapping, require protocol changes that make them incompatible with older table protocol versions.

See https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md#protocol-evolution

Comment: How to print the current protocol version?